# express an irrational as the sum of a rational and irrational number

Tags: irrational-numbers

Simple question, apologies. This is from some sample high school math questions, target is age 16 pupils. I don't think any great sophistication is expected.

$$
   P + Q = \sqrt {5}.
$$

$P$ is a rational number and $Q$ is an irrational number. Give possible values of $P$ and $Q$.

I can think of the trivial
$$
P = 0, 
Q = \sqrt {5}.
$$
I'm not even sure that the pupil would be expected to come up with
$$
P = 2, Q = (\sqrt {5} - 2).
$$
I don't think $Q$ could then be simplified to another named irrational. Any ideas what an expected answer might be?

Comment: Generalizing your own example, $P$ could be any rational!  If, say, $P=\frac mn$ then $Q=\sqrt 5 - \frac mn$.  One should argue that such a $Q$ is necessarily irrational, but this is straightforward.

Comment: Just so. My puzzle is what the target student was expected to give as an answer. I wondered if there was some value of P that can yield a simpler value of Q.

Comment: Well, I'd have thought that what I wrote was the intended answer.  For what it's worth $-1+2\phi=\sqrt 5$ where $\phi$ is the Golden Ratio.  But I don't think that simplifying $Q$ was the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $b\neq 0$ and let $P=\frac{a}{b}$. Then we have $Q=\sqrt 5 - P$ such that

$$
P+Q=\sqrt 5.
$$